# Complete intersections with respect to different sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

Let us consider the Whitney sum $E$ of holomorphic line bundles $L_1,\dots, L_k$ on a smooth (projective) variety $X$. For a generic global section $s$ of $E$, the zero locus $Z_s := s^{-1}(0_E)$ forms a (smooth) subvariety of $X$.

I would like to know how "similar" the subvarieties $X_s$ and $X_t$ for different generic sections $s$ and $t$ are.

I think that they are connected by a deformation family (i.e. we have a smooth proper map $f:Y \to B$ with connected $B$ such that $X_s \simeq f^{-1}(b)$ and $X_t \simeq f^{-1}(b')$), because some papers say so an implicit way. But I can not find any relevant information about my question in books/lecture notes on deformation theory.

**Can you tell me any relevant resources mentioning a precise statement about my question?**

Comment: You are right. Let $U$ be the open subset of $\mathbf P(H^0(X,E))$ corresponding to sections whose zero locus is smooth, and $Y \subset X \times U$ be the subset $\{(x,u) \mid u(x)=0 \}$. Then $Y \rightarrow U$ is the family you want.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you know any relevant reference around these things?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know a reference. I think the reason the papers you are reading don't give a reference is because the argument I gave is very elementary.